# Access class object in an anonymous type

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I create an anonymous type object through a LINQ query, as follows:

```
var users = from u in context.Users
                    join ug in context.UserGroups on u.UserId equals ug.FkUserId
                    join g in context.Groups on ug.FkGroupId equals g.GroupId
                    where u.FkBranchId == branchId || branchId == -1
                    select new { User = u, MinGroup = g };
```

I want to access the User object as users.User, and pass it to a sorting function as  below:

```
var orderedList = CustomSort<EFModel.ClientData.User>.GetSortedList(users.User, sortColumn, sortDirection).Skip(pageNo * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

but I get the following error:

> 'IQueryable<>' does not contain a definition for 'User' and no accessible extension method 'User' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable<>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Try accessing it like `users.ElementAt(0).User` or `users.Select(x => x.User)`

Comment: This is because `users` is a collection (not materialized yet). If you need a single user you can add `First` or `Last` to your query. If you not sure that your query contains  at least one item, use `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: I actually want to access the entire collection and pass it to a generic sorting function. Updated the code above.

Comment: Okay, I resolved it as Kunal suggested, thanks.